# Json keyerror python

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-rest-framework

This is the error I am facing While trying to "POST"

views.py file

```
def scent_data_pass(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    response = {}
    response["data"] = "Data has been saved"

    return JsonResponse(response, status=200)

if request.method == 'POST':
    response = {}
    json_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    name = json_data["name"]
    uuid = json_data["datatuuid"]
    saved = Scent_raw(
        name=name,
        device_uuid = uuid

    )
    saved.save()
    try:
        response['result'] = 'Success'
        response['message'] = saved.datatuuid
    except:
        response['result'] = 'Ouch!'
        response['message'] = 'Script has not ran correctly'
    return JsonResponse(response)
```

models.py file

```
class Scent_raw(TimeStampedModel):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="", editable=False)
datatuuid = models.UUIDField(max_length=100, default="", editable=False)
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Scent raw data'
    verbose_name_plural = "Scent raw data"

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.id}'
```

[image: This is the error I am getting through postman]

Why I am facing keyerror here ?

Comment: Please edit the Python code in your question so it is indented correctly, and add into your question the full error message ensuring that the line where the error occurs is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

In postman you are adding query parameters which is not the same as json. Go to the body tab, select JSON format and enter the following `{"name":"mitesh", "datauuid":"xyz"}`